# c++ how to use mocks instead of normal class

Tags: c++, mocking

```
class MyClass
{
public:
  MyClass()
  {
    otherClass = new ConcreteClass();
  }
private:
  void FuncA()
  {
    otherClass->FuncB();
  }

  IOtherClass* otherClass;
};
```

How should I redesign my code to use mock derived from IOtherClass instead of ConcreteClass? Suppose that I cannot change FuncA().

Comment: Do you mean: IOtherClass* otherClass = new IOtherClass(); ?

Comment: You may want to have a look at the googlemock framework. It automatically creates C++ class mocks.

Comment: The problem is not in creation of a mock, but in conveying it to a class.